# C# - MOUSEINPUT coordinates not setting properly when using SendInput

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dictionary

I am attempting to simulate mouse input using the SendInput method. The clicks and such are working correctly but the coordinates are not setting properly. Each time an input is executed, the mouse cursor moves to the bottom right corner of the screen. I have tried to change the MOUSEINPUT X and Y coordinates to the long data type [as listed in the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but then the SendInput method always returns an error and the inputs don't execute.

Below is the code I am using to attempt this. I have ported this code over from a similar implementation where KEYBDINPUT structures were created and executed. That implementation worked perfectly so I am confused as to why this does not. I am sure it is something very small as the mouse clicks etc. execute successfully it is just the coordinates causing the issue.

If anyone has any insight as to what is going wrong here, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SequenceAutomation
{
    #region Stucture declarations

    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public uint MouseData;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

    public struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint Msg;
        public ushort ParamL;
        public ushort ParamH;
    }

    public struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort KeyCode;
        public ushort Scan; 
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time; 
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MOUSEINPUT Mouse;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT Keyboard;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT Hardware;
    }

    public struct INPUT
    {
        public uint Type;
        public MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT Data; 
    }

    #endregion

    public class PlayRecording
    {
        #region Variable declarations

        public bool stopPlayback;
        private RecordingManager recManager;
        private float timeFactor; 
        private Dictionary<long, Dictionary<IntPtr, Dictionary<string, int>>> mouseDict;
        private Dictionary<long, INPUT[]> keysToPlay; 
        private Stopwatch watch;
        private long currentEntry;

        #endregion

        #region Libary importations

        // Importation of native libraries
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint SendInput(uint numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, int sizeOfInputStructure);

        #endregion

        #region Public methods

        public PlayRecording(string inputJson, float timeFactor)
        {
            currentEntry = 0;
            this.timeFactor = timeFactor;
            stopPlayback = false;
            watch = new Stopwatch();

            recManager = new RecordingManager(inputJson);
            recManager.getDictionaries(inputJson);
            mouseDict = recManager.mouseDict;

            inputsToPlay = new Dictionary<long, INPUT[]>();
            prepareInputsToPlay();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            currentEntry = 0; 
            watch.Reset();
            watch.Start();
            IEnumerator<long> enumerator = inputsToPlay.Keys.GetEnumerator(); 
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                while (watch.ElapsedTicks < (enumerator.Current * timeFactor)) { }

                if (!stopPlayback)
                    uint err = SendInput((uint)keysToPlay[enumerator.Current].Length, keysToPlay[enumerator.Current], Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));

                currentEntry = enumerator.Current; 
            }
        }


        public bool Stop()
        {
            watch.Stop();
            return true;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private methods

        private void prepareInputsToPlay()
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Dictionary<IntPtr, Dictionary<string, int>>> kvp in mouseDict)
            {
                List<INPUT> inputs = new List<INPUT>();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, Dictionary<string, int>> kvp2 in kvp.Value)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    int y = 0;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp3 in kvp2.Value)
                    {
                        if (kvp3.Key == "X")
                            x = Convert.ToInt32(kvp3.Value);
                        if (kvp3.Key == "Y")
                            y = Convert.ToInt32(kvp3.Value);
                    }
                    inputs.Add(loadMouse(x, y, getFlags(kvp2.Key)));
                }
                inputsToPlay.Add(kvp.Key, inputs.ToArray());
            }
        }

        // This is where the flags are set
        private uint getFlags(IntPtr activity)
        {
            string activityInt = Convert.ToString(activity);
            switch(activityInt)
            {
                    return 0x0002;
                case "512":
                    return 0x0001;
                case "513":
                    return 0x0002;
                case "514":
                    return 0x0004;
                case "516":
                    return 0x0008;
                case "517":
                    return 0x0010;
                case "522":
                    return 0x0800;
                default:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        // This is where the input structures are being created
        private INPUT loadMouse(int x, int y, uint flags)
        {
            return new INPUT
            {
                Type = 0,
                Data =
                {
                    Mouse = new MOUSEINPUT
                    {
                        X = x,
                        Y = y,
                        MouseData = 0,
                        Flags = flags,
                        Time = 0,
                        ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you include the flag `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` (0x8000) then the mouse coordinates are relative coordinates.  If you are passing absolute coordinates without this flag the mouse will rapidly move to one corner of the screen

Comment: How can I pass that flag while also passing other flags like left click, right click, and such? Also, what if I need to use the absolute coordinates? I am trying to record and simulate mouse input precisely so I would need the coordinates to match those originally recorded

Comment: Just OR that number with any other flag(s) you need to use.  Something like `getFlags(kvp2.Key) | 0x8000` within the inputs.Add line

Comment: Okay so I made this change to the code and now the cursor shoots to the top-left corner instead of the bottom right. It does move around, however. It mimics the movements exactly as recorded but only in a minuscule area in the upper-left corner. Any ideas what is happening here? It's as though the application thinks the screen size is about 2cm x 2cm. Is this related to the coordinates being integers rather than longs?

Comment: The values are from 0-65535, and are not pixels.  If you have pixel coordinates you would need to check the size of the PrimaryScreen and convert the numbers.  Something like `x = 65535 * x / Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width`.  But it would be tidier to look up the size of the screen once and store it.  The meaning of the coordinates is all in the remarks in the [MOUSEINPUT docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've marked your answer as the solution.